# Delete all document variables from a .docx file using Word 2007 VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to delete all document variables from a .docx file. I can see here (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306281) that it's easy enough to delete a variable by name, but unfortunately I don't have a list of the variable names.

Is there either:

1. A way to delete all variables at once?
2. If 1 isn't possible, is there a way to get a list of all the variable names that exist in the document, so I can loop across them to delete as shown in the link above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim x As Long

For x = ActiveDocument.Variables.Count to 1 Step -1
    ActiveDocument.Variables(x).Delete
Next x
```

Comment: Excellent, didn't realize the argument to .Variables could be a number instead of a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to unlink / delete the background code for the variables.